# ASP.NET MVC Upload image to Azure Storage Container

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, blob

Below is my code and it is working fine. But it saves a file which is not .jpeg type and it is 0 KB. What is wrong in the code?

[image]

Comment: Just add `ms.Position = 0` before you call `blockBlob.UploadFromStream` and that should fix the problem. Also, please paste the code instead of image :).

Comment: Yeah, it is working. Thanks!!!

Comment: And how can I display that image?

Comment: There are a few ways for displaying them. A) Make them anonymously accessible and embed using URL. B) Generate SAS token and embed using URL + token. C) Read and stream through your backend. I would recommend A or B.

Comment: @GauravMantri You should add your comment as an answer, it really helps me :)

Comment: Yes, it really helped!